# SQL - Joining a list of dates with observations within a date range

Tags: sql

I have a sample query below that uses GETDATE to pull the most recent estimates. The table has TWO date columns, effectiveDate and toDate. The problem? I want to pull a weekly value so I can have a time series of estimates. If I run the query now, I will end up with all the estimates as of today, but I also want to know what they were last week, the week before, etc.

Should I create a new table containing the dates that I want and then join them against the results of the query. This is where I am stuck. Thank you.

---

```
select GETDATE() as observeDate
, (select C.companyName from ciqCompany C where C.companyId = EP.companyId) as companyName
, (select EPT.periodTypeName from ciqEstimatePeriodType EPT where EPT.periodTypeId = EP.periodTypeId) as periodTypeName
, EP.fiscalYear
, EB.brokerName as brokerName
, EA.firstName+' '+EA.lastName as AnalystName
, EDND.tradingitemid
, (select DI.dataItemName from ciqdataitem DI where DI.dataitemid = EDND.dataitemid) as dataItemName
, (select EAS.accountingStandardDescription from dbo.ciqEstimateAccountingStd EAS where EAS.accountingStandardId = EDND.accountingStandardId) as AccountingStandard
, (select Cu.ISOCode from ciqCurrency Cu where Cu.currencyid = EDND.currencyid) as ISOCode
, (select EST.estimateScaleName from ciqEstimateScaleType EST where EST.estimateScaleId = EDND.estimateScaleId) as estimateScaleName
,EDND.dataItemValue,EDND.effectiveDate,EDND.isExcluded
from ciqEstimatePeriod EP
--- link estimate period table to detailed numeric data table
----------------------------------------------------------
join ciqEstimateDetailNumericData EDND
on EDND.estimatePeriodId = EP.estimatePeriodId
and GETDATE() between EDND.effectiveDate and EDND.toDate
----------------------------------------------------------
left outer join ciqEstimateBroker EB
on EB.estimateBrokerId = EDND.estimateBrokerId --- left outer join must be used if you receive any of the anonymous estimates packages
left outer join ciqEstimateAnalyst EA
on EA.estimateAnalystId = EDND.estimateAnalystId --- left outer join must be used if you receive any of the anonymous estimates packages
where EP.companyId = 112350 -- IBM
and EP.periodTypeId = 1 -- annual
and EDND.dataItemId = 21634 --- EPS Normalized (Detailed)
and EP.fiscalYear = 2010
order by 4,5,6,10
```

Comment: Is it slow?  Why do you have all the subqueries vs inner joins in the top part?

Answer (score 0):

This query is complicated enough as it is - I would hate to add to it.  I would probably turn it into a view or a stored proc and query from it as needed.  Then you could also have, instead of just GETDATE(), a date range as input.

Comment: The database I'm pulling from is a complicated one and the I took the query from the vendor's documentation. But the documentation is geared to pulling one set of observations at a given point in time rather than pulling a historical time series, which I am trying to do...